# Android 4.0.3 emulator: the connection to the server was unsuccessful

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, android-emulator

Having problem with emulators android 4.0.3 it is work on android emulators 2.2, 2.3.3 but
on emulators 4.0.3 getting The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (`file:///android_asset/www/index.html`), using phonegap 2.2.0

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 6000);
    }
```

Looking for days for answer did not find, Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move this line `super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 6000);` following:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 6000);
     super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
 }
```

Hope it works for you.